# Override CSS value to be empty in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have a Flex 3.2 application for which I am developing a custom style.  Basically the first stylesheet gets applied first, and then my custom stylesheet.  I am wondering how I can completely empty a value set in the first stylesheet with a value set in the second.  The value has to be blank because if the horizontal-center value is set then any other positioning values are ignored.  I have attempted null and "" with no luck.  Any ideas?

Example

```
CSS1.css
.myButton {
    horizontal-center: 0;
}

CSS2.css
.myButton {
    horizontal-center: ??
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `NaN` or `undefined` - just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you need is runtime style selection in ActionScript:

```
StyleManager.setStyleDeclaration("SelectorName", styleName, true);
StyleManager.clearStyleDeclaration("SelectorName", styleName);
```

Where `styleName` is an instance of `CSSStyledeclaration`, and `SelectorName` would in your case likely be "Button"

See the page for StyleManager in the liveDocs.

Comment: this may work in other applications,  but I am not executing any custom ActionScript code, just custom CSS files.